# Firebase error. Please ensure that you have the URL of your Firebase Realtime Database instance configured correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, next.js, fetch-api

I am using `getServerSideProps` to fetch data from my firebase database into my Next.js application.

My code snippet looks like this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const session = await getSession(context);
    const products = await fetch("https://database-73695.firebaseio.com/").then(
      (res) => res.json()
    );

    return {
      props: {
        products,
        session
      },
    };
  }
```

The problem is that I get error message saying the following: `"FetchError: invalid json response body at https://database-73695.firebaseio.com/ reason: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 0"`

I have seen that some people report this error when the data fetched is actually text and not an object. I tried changing the response from res.json to `res.text`, but then I'm told that `"text is undefined"`.

Does anybody have any idea of what could be happening?

UPDATE:
By testing different fetching methods, I have seen the error:

`Firebase error. Please ensure that you have the URL of your Firebase Realtime Database instance configured correctly.`

All fetching code (with or without getServerSideProps) work when used with other APIs.
My database URL comes from Firestore, and is formated as follows:

https://PROJECT-ID.firebaseio.com

It is located in us-central, which I know is important for the URL.

Something else that might be worth noting: the database has already a collection called "users" tied to Stripe transactions, which works.

Any ideas?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you able to successfully fetch data from that endpoint outside `getServerSideProps` and/or in Postman?

Comment: Hello @juliomalves. Thank you for your response. I tried in Postman, and the response I get is "Firebase error. Please ensure that you have the URL of your Firebase Realtime Database instance configured correctly."

Comment: Then that's probably the same error you get in `getServerSideProps`. Have you checked you have the URL configured correctly, like the message says?

Comment: @juliomalves Thank you for taking the time to respond.
I am using the URL format https://<projectId>.firebaseio.com
The database is setup on Firestore, which, correct me if I'm wrong, shouldn't make a difference... but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

->try adding headers:

headers:
{
Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
'User-Agent': '*',
},

->try checking if data is not been fetch from the back-end

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I appreciate it. I have tried the above code, changing the * for my browser's User Agent. Nothing happened, the error remained the same. 
I tried using a different API (myfakestore and json placeholder) and the code works, data is fetched and displayed on the frontend. 

I'm assuming this means there is something wrong with the configuration of my database... if you have any further ideas, let me know. I appreciate your time in any case.